# Howler.js to play audio from websocket via Rails ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, audio-streaming, actioncable, howler.js

I am trying to play an audio stream with Howler.js. The stream is on a websocket via Rails ActionCable.

I know that I can get Howler to play the stream using the code below:

```
var player = new Howl({
        src: 'wss://mywebsite.com/stream',
        html5: true,
        format: ['wav']
    });
player.play();
```

However the stream in question is actually hosted by a Ruby on Rails app via ActionCable. So I need to pass in 2 params to ActionCable as shown below:

```
consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "MyAudioChannel", my_stream_id: "1234" }
```

But how would I pass this info along on Howler.js?

Comment: What you have isn't correct as per the Howler.js documentation. The argument you pass to `src` should be an array of URLs or base64 data URIs, not a WebSocket URI.